# Add column with calculated fields which is 5 years later from an inserted date in access.

Tags: database

So I've got an access database in which there is a "date" column and "expiration date" column. I want to add another column to the database which automatically gives me the expiration date, 5 years later from the date that is inserted in the "date" column. What is the code for the calculated field?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

In the first one the +1 is the number of years

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+5,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```